# Grafting Scala 2.8 into a Netbeans NBAndroid Project...What steps am I missing?

Tags: android, scala, netbeans6.8

Due to Apple's recent T+C hijinks, I've become interested in developing for Android.

Anyways, I'm trying to get a mixed-language Android 2.1 project going in Netbeans 6.8 (with the NBAndroid 0.10 plugin). The two languages being Java and Scala(2.8 head build). To give you a basic idea of what the app does right now, it's just a simple "Hello World" app.

To get this to build, I've modified the projects's build.xml file:

```
 <target name="-pre-compile" depends="init">
   <property name="scala-home" value="/Users/development/Applications/scala-2.8.0/build/pack"/>
   <property name="scala-library" value="/Users/development/Applications/scala-2.8.0/build/pack/lib/scala-library.jar"/>
   <echo message="scala-library = ${scala-library}"/>
   <echo message="scala-home = ${scala-home}"/>
   <echo message="platform.bootcp = ${platform.bootcp}"/>
   <echo message="dist.apk.dir = ${dist.apk.dir}"/>
   <echo message="build.classes.dir = ${build.classes.dir}"/>
   <path id="build.classpath">
     <pathelement location="${scala-library}"   />
     <!--<pathelement location="${your.path}"   />-->
     <pathelement location="${build.classes.dir}"   />
   </path>
   <taskdef resource="scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="${scala.home}/lib/scala-compiler.jar"   />
       <pathelement location="${scala-library}"   />
       <pathelement location="${javac.classpath}" /> 
     </classpath>
   </taskdef>
   <scalac srcdir="${src.ScalaSource.dir}" destdir="${build.classes.dir}" >
      <classpath>
       <pathelement location="/Users/development/Documents/AndroidTest/scala-library.jar"   />
       <pathelement location = "${scala-library}" />
       <pathelement location = "${file.reference.android.jar}" />
       <pathelement path="${javac.classpath}" /> 
     </classpath>
   </scalac>
   <echo message="file.reference.android.jar: ${file.reference.android.jar}"/>
   <echo message="file.reference.scala-library.jar: ${file.reference.scala-library.jar}"/>
 </target>

 <target name="-pre-jar">
        <!-- Empty placeholder for easier customization. -->
        <!-- You can override this target in the ../build.xml file. -->
 <taskdef resource="proguard/ant/task.properties"
   classpath="tools/proguard.jar" />
 <proguard>
   -injars ${scala-library}(!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,!library.properties)
   -outjars "${build.classes.dir}/classes.min.jar"
   -libraryjars "${file.reference.android.jar}"
   -dontwarn
   -dontoptimize
   -dontobfuscate
   -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
   -keep public class scala.xml.include.sax.Main**
 </proguard>
    </target>
```

I've gotten the project so that it'll build, but it errors on startup in my Android Emulator(inside the emulator Android tells me my application has stopped unexpectedly).

So my questions are: Does anyone see what I may be doing wrong? And is there any way to get access to the logs that the emulator must create?

thanks

**Edit**:  FYI, here's the output from adb logcat:

```
I/dalvikvm(  369): Failed resolving Lorg/me/androidtest/MainActivity; interface 35 'Lscala/ScalaObject;'
W/dalvikvm(  369): Link of class 'Lorg/me/androidtest/MainActivity;' failed
D/AndroidRuntime(  369): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  369): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.me.androidtest/org.me.androidtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.me.androidtest.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02720
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.me.androidtest.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@43d02720
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
E/AndroidRuntime(  369):    ... 11 more
I/Process (   56): Sending signal. PID: 369 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  369): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  369): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
W/ActivityManager(   56): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
```

Clearly, it's some type of classloader/classpath issue or something(at least that's what I'd say if this was the JVM), but when I look inside my Proguard'd jarfile I find The classes I'd expect:  scala.ScalaObject, org.me.androidtest.MainActivity, and some others.

If it helps the project with all it's dependencies made internal is located at http://philosophicalsoftware.com/AndroidTest.zip

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone see what I may be doing
>   wrong?

Yes. You don't have any source code. :-)

> And is there any way to get access to
>   the logs that the emulator must
>   create?

I'm not sure about inside of Netbeans, but you can use `adb logcat` or DDMS to examine the logs, which will contain...well...something. Ordinarily, I'd say "a Java stack trace showing the cause of your exception", but I'm not 100% certain what happens with a Scala app (though I am planning on doing some Scala/Android experiments soonish).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and finally found the solution:)

In my case, I was not changing the value of property `out.dex.input.absolute.dir` (in SDK Tools r8) to jar file that was generated by Proguard. So, the `ScalaObject` interface was really not present in apk file.

(I discovered that using great [apktool](http://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/).)